# inline block with fadein

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I have a small problem with a list definition. Basically, I have a fadein effect on my lists (which works) but the problem is that when my `<li>` appear, they are not inline-block. So I add the inline-block in the JS, but fadein vanishes ..

```
 function fadeLI(elem) { 
  elem.fadeIn(500, function() { 
    fadeLI($(this).next().css("display","inline-block")); 
  }); 
 }

 fadeLI($("#portfolio li:first"));
```

Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/mqthK/426/

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you against using `float: left;` on the list-items? http://jsfiddle.net/mqthK/428/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function fadeLI(elem) { 
    elem.css('opacity', '0').addClass('test').stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow', function() { 
        var $next = $(this).next();
        if($next.length)
            fadeLI($next); 
    }); 
}

fadeLI($("#test li:first"));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Nm3fN/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 .test {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mqthK/429/